# Is the Jew versus Gentile/Tax Collector theme an interpretive framework for the gospel of Luke?

Tags: luke, gospels, parables

There seems to be a Jew vs Gentile theme running in the gospel of Luke.Most of the parables seem to pit the faith of Jews vs that of Gentiles/Samaritans/tax collectors

Luke 5:27-32

***Levi the Tax Collector***

Pharisees/Jews vs Tax collector

Luke 7:1-9

***The faith of the Centurion***

Jews vs Roman Centurion

Luke 10:30-36

***The Parable of good Samaritan***

Priest/Levite/jew vs Samaritan

Luke 11:36

***The Queen of the south***

Jews vs the queen

Luke 13:24-30

***The Narrow Door***

Jews vs many/foreigners

Luke 14:16-24

***The Parable of Great Banquet***

Jews vs poor/crippled

Luke 15:1-7

***The Parable of the lost Sheep***

Jews vs Tax collectors/sinners

Luke 17:11-18

***Ten Lepers***

Jews vs Samaritan

Luke 18:9-15

***The Parable of the Pharisee***

Jew vs Tax collector

Luke 19:1-9

***Zacchaeus the Tax  Collector***

Jews vs Tax Collector/sinner

Could this theme be an interpretive framework for understanding this gospel?

Comment: Yes, it _could_ be, but only if you prove it by developing it further, I would suggest. Up-voted +1, in the hope that you manage to do so.

Comment: @NigelJ,will try

Comment: +1 interesting theory

Answer (score 1):

A case can be made for Luke's gospel focus on the Gentiles more than the other three gospels. E.g., when Jesus was 8 days ago, his parents brought him to the temple. Simeon prophesied over Jesus in  Luke 2:

> 29 “Sovereign Lord, as You have promised,
> You now dismiss Your servant in peace.
> 30 For my eyes have seen Your salvation,
> 31 which You have prepared in the sight of all people,
> 32 **a light for revelation to the Gentiles**,
> and for glory to Your people Israel.”

The above is found only in Luke.

Answer (score 0):

### Luke 6:20-26

> **20** And he lifted up his eyes on his disciples, and said:
> *“Blessed are **you who are poor,** for yours is the kingdom of God.
> **21** “Blessed are **you** **who are hungry now,** for you shall be satisfied.
> “Blessed are **you who weep now,** for you shall laugh.

### **22** *“Blessed are **you when people hate you** and when they **exclude you** and **revile you** and **spurn your name as evil,** on account of the Son of Man!*

> **23** Rejoice in that day, and leap for joy, for behold, your reward is great in heaven;
> **for so their fathers did to the prophets.***
> **24** ***“But woe to you who are rich,** for you have received your consolation.
>
> **25** **“Woe to you who are full now,** for you shall be hungry.
>
> **“Woe to you who laugh now,** for you shall mourn and weep.
>
> **26** **“Woe to you, when all people speak well of you,**
>
> for so their fathers did to the false prophets.*

**“Most of the parables seem to pit the faith of Jews vs that of Gentiles/Samaritans/tax collectors. Could this theme be an interpretive framework for understanding this gospel?”**

I think so, except I don’t think this is necessarily about Jew vs. Gentiles/Samaritans/Tax collectors specifically but instead the criminally corrupt ruling class of the Jews against everyone else Jew or Gentile whom they economically defrauded or politically designated as outcasts but of whom Christ thought worthy to call brothers.
***The disbelieving and predatory in-crowd are cast out of the kingdom of God,  while the believing and dispised outsiders are invited in to inherit it.***